# Chat Rest Api ChasitorInit response OK but not reach to online agent

Tags: rest-api, chat

I am trying ChasitorInit, response status is OK but chat request is not see in the Live Agent widget. What reasons can we consider about this?
Thanks in advanced.
ref:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386079&type=1

Regards,
LinThaw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved when I changed chat button id digit from 18 to 15.